# Serialization integration solution in java and c#?

Tags: java, c#, serialization

I have two apps , one build with c# ,another build with JAVA.
Both of them has a "compareJsonService" ,and the same logic.

The detail of the logic:

```
public void compareJsonService(int id,Person personFromCenter){
    PersonDTO person = personRepository.getByPK(id);
    if(!person.getJson().equals(JsonUtil.serialize(personFromCenter)){
        personRepository.updatePerson(convertPersonToDTO(personFromCenter,person));
    }
}
```

The object personFromCenter is unique ,no matter in java app or c# app.
They get the personDTO from database by pk ,and compare the field json,when the result is fasle,then update.

But the result of serialization is not equal ,I think this is caused by the different serialization mechanisms of java and c#.

they both use equals method to compare the output,then always get false (because their serialized string comparison values ​​are different).so ,they always update .
The problem is ,I want a solution something like a restful interface that pass Person object and return a json String ,so whether Java or c# use this service, they get the same serialized output .

So,before I migrate all c# code to Java ,How many solutions to solve the problem ?And Which one is the easiest way?

Comment: How are they different? Which one seems "correct"? Or more correct?

Comment: @Flydog57 They have different order of attributes after serialization.. But it's not the point...

Comment: @Flydog57 they both "correct"

Comment: So, the serialized outputs are both "correct". Can Java read the C# serialized output and vice-versa? If so, then, what's the problem; they are equivalent.

Comment: @Flydog57 they both use equals method to compare the output,then always get false (because their serialized string comparison values ​​are different).so ,they always update .The problem is ,I want a solution something like a restful interface that pass Person object and return a json String ,so whether Java or c# use this service, they get the same serialized output

Comment: So you are comparing the serialized versions of objects?  Even if you get that to work, it's likely to be fragile.  Someone might change the serializer so that a value of 42.0 changes from "42" to 42.0" when serialized. You should consider another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn the json string to an object (for example with Jackson library in Java) and compare the result Java/C# Object.
Even if you get different orders in the json string if you compare object you should be able to know if they are equals or not.